# Appium Automation: Getting error - org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to parse remote response: Parameters were incorrect

Tags: java, android, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, appium

I am trying to do appium android automation using Java. Below is the code:

```
public class Main {

AppiumDriver driver;

@Before
public void setup() throws Exception{
    DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("platformVersion","4.4");
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("app","/PATH_TO_APK");
    driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"),desiredCapabilities);
}

@After
public void tearDown(){
    driver.quit();
}

@Test
public void firstTest(){
    WebElement element = driver.findElementById("ELEMENT_ID");
    element.click();
}
}
```

Below is the error

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to parse remote response: Parameters were incorrect. We wanted {"required":["desiredCapabilities"],"optional":["requiredCapabilities","sessionId","id","sessionId","id","sessionId","id","sessionId","id","sessionId","id","sessionId","id"]} and you sent ["desiredCapabilities","requiredCapabilities","capabilities"]
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'WGB01ML106163.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:3e15:c2ff:febe:8ea0%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.6', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
```

Has anyone seen this error before? Cant find anything on Google. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

We also need to pass the "deviceName" in the capabilities.

```
 desiredCapabilities.setCapability("deviceName","Android");
```

Also, if you doing hybrid/native app testing in the mobile, we need to pass appPackage and appActivity also. So combining all the mandatory capabilities, overall desired capabilities will look similar to this.

```
public void setup() throws Exception
{
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","ANDROID");
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.1");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName",Constant.appPlatform);
capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", Constant.appPackage);
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity",Constant.appActivity);

driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4727/wd/hub"),capabilities);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Easy way to get appActivity/appPackage is contacting your developer. If not possible check this=>[appActivity/appPackage](http://toolsqa.com/mobile-automation/appium/how-to-find-apppackage-and-appactivity-for-apk-file/)

More details about various capabilities are available here.

https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps.md

Comment: I have added the "deviceName" capability but still seeing the same error.

Comment: @Anshul have updated the answer. Check and let me know if it works

Comment: thanks Santhosh for your help. My appium version was 1.5.3. This issue is resolved after I upgraded appium to latest version 1.6.4.