# Unable to understand WebDriver execption?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I am getting Web-driver exception while running a selenium code for grid.Here is code detail:

Chrome Version : 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)
Selenium server : 3.4.0

```
@Test
public void Testgrid() throws MalformedURLException{
    DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    cap.setBrowserName("chrome");
    cap.setPlatform(Platform.ANY);
    cap.setCapability("binary", "C:\\Program Files(x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");
    RemoteWebDriver  driver = new RemoteWebDriver(newURL("http://localhost:4444/wb/hub"), cap);
    driver.get("https://www.simplesite.com/pages/service-login.aspx");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}
```

Exception:
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to parse remote response:

Comment: Missed error content.Here is detail:Here is error details:

FAILED: Testgrid
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to parse remote response: <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: Please update your **question** to include the Exception.

Comment: @TimothyCope added exception

Comment: I see a similar error message in this Q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43685258/appium-automation-getting-error-org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-unabl. I know you aren't using Appium but are all your Selenium-related drivers current?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this :

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E://chromedriver.exe");

set this property in your code before DesiredCapabilities.

or in node command give this command:

java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=E:\chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.5.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -port 4422

this worked for me once. I am not sure of using -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=E:\chromedriver.exe here , you can edit it to -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=E:\chromedriver.exe